# Syntax: using Vectorize to vectorize a multidimensional function in this example R

Tags: r, function, syntax, vectorization, interpolation

I am looking at the last example in this short docs:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/chebpol/versions/1.3-952/topics/mlappx

Reproduced here,

```
require(chebpol)
## evenly spaced grid-points
su <- seq(0,1,length.out=10)
## irregularly spaced grid-points
s <- su^3
## create approximation on the irregularly spaced grid
ml1 <- Vectorize(mlappx(exp,list(s)))
## test it, since exp is convex, the linear approximation lies above
## the exp between the grid points
ml1(su) - exp(su)

## multi linear approx
f <- function(x) exp(sum(x^2))
grid <- list(s,su)

ml2 <- mlappx(evalongrid(f,grid=grid),grid)
# an equivalent would be ml2 <- mlappx(f,grid)

a <- runif(2); ml2(a); f(a)
# we also get an approximation outside of the domain, of disputable quality
ml2(c(1,2)); f(c(1,2))
```

The last line evaluates the approximation (via linear interpolation) of `f` for the point (1,2).   What the the darned syntax to get it to evaluate multiple pairs of points if we vectorize with:

```
ml2 <- Vectorize(mlappx(evalongrid(f,grid=grid),grid))
```

Comment: The syntax for `Vectorize` is `vF <- Vectorize(F)` where `F` is a (scalar) function.  You don't need the arguments etc that you have included.  You can then use `vF` just like `F`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar  Can you show me how in the above exampe to get ml2 to evaulate the two pairs of points (.5,.5) and (1,2) ?

Comment: Perhaps `sapply(list(c(.5,.5),c(1,2)),ml2)`

Answer (score 2):

Just a short note. I'm the author of chebpol. Recently I've upgraded it with several more interpolation methods. They have a uniform interface through the ipol() function, and are all vectorized (they can take a matrix of column vectors), and are parallelized.